# Convert text string into a formula in Excel

Tags: excel, text, excel-formula

I have in a cell two numbers "=5+4" as a text. This is a result of another operation.

I took a part of another formula and concatenated it with "equal" symbol:

```
= "="   &    RIGHT(FORMULATEXT(V8);LEN(FORMULATEXT(V8))-SEARCH("+"; FORMULATEXT(V8)))
```

I want to get the result of 5+4 in a cell- which means "9" ;)
I DO NOT WANT TO USE VBA code.

Comment: Your only option is a macro function of some kind whether VBA or XLM.

Comment: then maybe from the other side: my initial problem was to extract all numbers except the first one from an equation and sum in another cell: A1: "=6+5+4". A2: "9". Maybe it can be solved without VBA?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://superuser.com/questions/1515531/opposite-of-formulatext-in-excel

Comment: Use the cell value and just subtract the first number: `=A1-MID(FORMULATEXT(A1);2;FIND("+";FORMULATEXT(A1))-2)`

Comment: Is the only operation within the string addition? Or might there be subtraction, multiplication, etc.?

Answer (score 4):

> *my initial problem was to extract all numbers except the first one from an equation and sum in another cell: A1: "=6+5+4". A2: "9". Maybe it can be solved without VBA?*

You could try (assuming only addition):

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,2,LEN(A1)),"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>1]"))
```

In fact, if you don't want to use the 1st number we could also discard taking '=' into account:

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s[position()>1]"))
```

And since `SUM()` will ignore text in the final answer, we can now even further simplify this (thanks @JosWoolley):

```
=SUM(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"+","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))
```

Comment: You could simplify your second formula even further: `[position()>1]` is redundant, since `SUM` will ignore the first (text) entry beginning with "=" in the array passed to it.

Comment: @JosWoolley, exactly! Good catch. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 2):

If you are always adding 2 numbers, then you can use this:

[image]

```
=VALUE(VALUE(MID(A1;2;SEARCH("+";A1)-2))+VALUE(MID(A1;SEARCH("+";A1)+1;9999)))
```

My column A is formatted as text, and all values follow same pattern: `=Value1+Value2`

So the formula extracts `Value1` and `Value2` as text with MID functions, based on the position of `+` symbol. Then Excel convert both values into numeric with VALUE function. Notice there are 3 values, the third one is to make sure the cell stays at standar format (in some versions of Excel, like mine 2007, when involving text formatted cells into formulas, the formulated cell autoformat itself to text format, making the formula to work just once).

As you can see in the image, it works perfectly but this is just for pattern `=Value1+Value2`. For different patters you'll need different formulas.

If you want to make a formula to work with all patterns, then indeed you need VBA.